# How to call a function with onPress ? React Native TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, touchableopacity

I am currently trying to make an app with React Native but I am facing a problem that i don't understand.

I want to get the id of the element the user touched, I try to do this using a onPress in a

```
      tasks.map(element => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={(element) => getTouchedId(element)}>
             <Note text={element.text} color={element.color} setpositionX={setpositionX} setpositionY={setpositionY}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })}
```

So onPress call getTouchedId and pass element as a parameter.

Here is my getTouchedId function :

```
  const getTouchedId = (element) => {
    console.log("element.id : " + element.id)
    settouchedId(element.id)
  }
```

So here you can see my function, I dont understand why I am never seeing my `console.log("element.id : " + element.id)` I think the problem is that my function is never red and I don't understand why (the value of `touchedId` with `settouchedId` also never changes).

Answer (score 1):

Change `onPress={(element) => getTouchedId(element)}` to

`onPress={() => getTouchedId(element)}`.

The reason is `element` here `onPress={(element)` is representing the event originating on `pressing` but the not the element from the array

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.dev/JXy_X2gd5)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and for the demo. Unfortunately the problem is not solved. Your  code is perfeclty  working when i replace my `<Note/>` compoenent by a `<Text>`. My Note component is using a `Draggable` from react-native-draggable, and i think because of that React is not able to detect when somone press. If you've got any Idea to how to solve that I'll be happy to know, I'll keep searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.

```js
tasks.map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => getTouchedId(element, index)}>
             <Note text={element.text} color={element.color} setpositionX={setpositionX} setpositionY={setpositionY}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })}
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the improvement, but still not working, I will search for a solution when I have the time, and if I find it, I will answear my own question

Comment: did you use log in the method `getTouchedId` ?  If console.log works then i think, there is a problem with your implementation code in the method.

Comment: No console.log was not working, but i found a solution to get the id of my element by giving a function in the props, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure onPress function has element parameter?

onPress defined like

```
({ nativeEvent: PressEvent }) => void
```

PressEvent defined like

```
{
    changedTouches: [PressEvent],
    identifier: 1,
    locationX: 8,
    locationY: 4.5,
    pageX: 24,
    pageY: 49.5,
    target: 1127,
    timestamp: 85131876.58868201,
    touches: []
}
```